# Run-time Error 5: Invalid Procedure - Changing Pivot Table Source & Refresh Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, office365, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I try to Change/Edit the source of pivot Table and refresh the pivot after that but get the 'Run-time error '5', Invalid procedure call or argument.
I get a successful result on my computer with office 64 bit, and try to run it in other computer  with office 32 bit, first it run smoothly but after it upgrade to Office 64 bit, it gets an 'Run-time error '5', Invalid procedure call or argument error.

Please help.

```
Windows("Master.xlsb").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$" & vmLastRec).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array("PrApprovedComplete")
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
vmRow = Selection.Row
Range("A" & vmRow & ":P" & vmRow).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Windows("Daily Report PR.xlsb").Activate
Sheets("Need to Handle").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
vmRow = Selection.Row

Range("T3").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
    PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    vmWorkDir & "[Daily Report PR.xlsb]Need to Handle!R1C1:R" & vmRow & "C16", _
    Version:=8)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Hope its run on this new installed Office 64 bit.